# How can I export books from Ubuntu to Amazon Kindle?

Tags: 12.04, calibre, kindle

I have tried the Amazon Kindle HD 7", but could not integrate it at all with my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS OS.

I have tried the USB cable but it didn't show up on the screen and I have tried to connect it via Bluetooth, but it also didn't work.

I have Calibre installed on my Ubuntu, but could not integrate it/export books to Kindle.
I have also tried to use Ubuntu One, but Amazon has its own cloud system.
Does anyone of you have any solution for these problems?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

send them via email to your kindle account. Calibre has an option for that. If you are unfamiliar every kindle has a unique email that you can send documents to.,

Answer (score 2):

You may try installing SendToKindle program written in python.

First install python setup tools:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Then follow instructions on github repository:

https://github.com/miracle2k/sendtokindle#installation

After installation you should be able to send any file via right mouse click.